# Contact Form 7 - Admin side fields validation

Tags: wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I am developing Contact Form 7 Extension.
I have create one tab called **"Test"** **beside "Additional Settings"** and I have added Some fields inside **"Test"** tab  and I am storing that fields value in post meta using `update_post_meta` function.
Now I want to add server side validation. For that I have tried followiing code

```
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'wpcf7_save_contact_form',  array( &$this, 'action_wpcf7_save_contact_form'), 10, 3 ); 
}


function action_wpcf7_save_contact_form( $contact_form,  $args,  $context ) { 

 if ( $_POST['test1'] == '' || $_POST['test2'] == '' || $_POST['test3'] == '' ) {

     echo '<div class="required_error">Please Fill Required Fields</div>';

 } 

}
```

But when I click on save button, It's not showing error.

Comment: Have you checked if the function is getting called at all or whether its the `if` thats failing?

Comment: @fluffykitten Yes, When I `print_r` array and `die` execution, it prints the array. But when I remove `die` It not showing any error.

Comment: I also tried to add `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'test_admin_notice__error' );` hook after `if` conditon. But it also not working.

Comment: Is there any hook for admin side **save** button in Contact Form 7 ?